# Importing bootstrap less to extend a class creates 404 on glyphicons fonts

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, less

In my Angular 2 application, I switched from raw css to less so that I can write:

```
.main-button {
  .btn;
  .btn-primary;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

instead of stacking class names everywhere in my html. To get this to work, I needed to:

1. in `angular-cli.json`, change:

   `"defaults": {
     "styleExt": "css",
     "prefixInterfaces": false
   }`

   to `"styleExt": "less",`
2. Rename my `foo.component.css` to `foo.component.less` and update the `foo.component.ts` accordingly.
3. In the component less, to be able to reference the bootstrap classes, I had to: `@import "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap";`

This works fine except that I'm now getting 404 errors in the browser console:

```
jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2 (anonymous function) @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2i @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2fireWith @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2ready @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2K @ jquery-1.12.3.min.js:2
foobar:1 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff 
foobar:1 GET http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
```

I tried a few variations on @icon-font-path without success. I checked the requests for fonts in the network tab and see `http://localhost:4200/448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2`.

I also tried to use sass/scss. This requires the additional module bootstrap-sass with a similar include directive but the result is exactly the same.

What is the right way to do this without having 404 errors ?

This is served by `ng serve`, it's all default there.

Comment: Do you have some kind of .htacces that caches "http://localhost:4200/node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/bootstrap/..." as a route instead of a file?

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you probably want to [import by reference](https://css-tricks.com/reference-imports-in-less-are-kinda-cool/). Otherwise it will include whole Bootstrap into your component styles, which may be not what you want. E.g. `@import (reference) "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap";` and extend only classes you need (see article).

Comment: Mike: It's a simple ng serve, so there is nothing special that could interfere.
YaroslavAdmin: Very interesting, thanks. Doesn't help but I'll use it.

Comment: Are You using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem with sass:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/bootstrap/";
@import "~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
```

https://github.com/igorzg/angular2-zero-to-hero/blob/master/ui/src/styles.scss

So for less should be in your styles.less:

```
$icon-font-path: "~bootstrap/fonts/";
@import "~bootstrap/less/bootstrap";
```

Comment: This is the correct solution. It didn't work for me when you replied apparently because I had included it in a specific file, not the master styles.scss. (I switched to SASS in the mean time)
Migrating to Angular 4, the tests were failing because of these warnings. Adding these two lines at the top of styles.scss solved it. There might have been an additional issue in Angular 2 fixed on Angular 4, hard to tell.

Comment: @EricDarchis It was not issue in angular 2 you had to same thing import it in main css and switch to scss

Answer (score 0):

Angular-CLI will bundle your font like this 448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2.
If you want the raw files, maybe you have to publish them on your server...

Comment: I would rather have less/scss use that bundled font instead. But no idea on how to do that since I'm just importing the definitions from my less file.

Comment: But the problem is with jQuery, not with Angular and CSS. Isn't it ?

Comment: If you want to request `http://localhost:4200/node_modules/some_file` you have to expose it with an alias or a proxy. In dev environnement, you could make a proxy.conf.json file as shown here: https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy, and launch your server with  `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

Answer (score 0):

Try: `ng set defaults.styleExt scss`

Angular-cli **must match** global and local versions

Run `ng init` check for changes in all the auto-generated files

Finally `ng build`

To keep everything in sync also try:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/angular-cli.git
cd angular-cli
npm link
```

For the fonts and assets, right now angular-cli assumes the path based on the source files:

```
"assets": [ "assets", "favicon.ico" ]
```

Comment: I tried both less and scss. `ng set defaults.styleExt` actually only changes the line in my question. It's also very buggy and tends to mess up the angular-cli.json but that's irrelevant here. Anyhow, all the assets are there, fonts included. And they work. It's just that including the bootstrap less in my component.less tries to locate the fonts with its full name rather than the packed one.